# How to know if a certain Node is the Head of an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers, javascript-injection

I'm working on a chrome extension that will add some features to an existing page. But for that, I need to add a script to a page **as soon as possible**!! (No, I cannot simply run a content script that starts before everything, I need this particular script to be inserted **into the DOM**)

(Why? Because that page loads everythin using ajax calls, and I need to be able to perform some operations *before* those calls)

So I intent to add the script the sooner I can immediately after the head of the document appears.

I'm looking at `MutationsObserver`, and it seems it could do that job. But how can I check if a certain `Node` from the `addedNodes` collection is the head???

Comment: look at the tagName of the node to see whether it is `HEAD`

Comment: You could also hook one of the `XMLHttpRequest` methods and catch things when the JS in the page tries to run its first ajax call.

Comment: Thank you for your help.... I just found out that mutation observer just doesn't work at all.....

Comment: @jfriend00, that is **exactly** what I'm doing. And that is **precisely** the reason why I need to inject this script before any of those ajax calls (In a chrome extension, I'm unable to catch the requests if I don't inject the script **into the DOM**)

Comment: Maybe this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like maybe this provided you an answer to your actual problem, I'll post it as an answer.

You can use the Chrome plug-in API to directly intercept the Ajax requests using this:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: This seems to be a pretty easy solution. But I tried it in my extension and `chrome.webRequest` is `undefined`. I added it to the manifest file as told in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. - The duplicate answer works though. The `documentElement` is present from the beginning and I can add the script into it.